# Nvidia drivers not loading

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nouveau

I'm using Kubuntu 15.04 with the latest kernel at the moment (4.2rc7) from here: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-rc7-unstable/ and the latest Nvidia drivers form ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa for my GeForce GT 740. I tried installing the latest beta driver (355.06) and stable driver (352.30) in separate instances each through the Driver Manager in the System Settings tab and after that using Ctrl + Alt + F1 to go another terminal session I used

```
systemctl stop sddm
systemctl start sddm
```

but after that using the

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

command there is no "Kernel driver in use:" line. If I try rebooting then the Nouveau driver kicks in, but not the Nvidia one. More curios is that the Driver Manager reverts to the Nouveau option and not the previosly set Nvidia proprietary driver option.

PS: I don't know if it matters but I'm using Plasma 5.3.2 from ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports

Does anyone know why won't the Nvidia driver load?

Comment: You use too many unsupported and unstable packages to resolve this.

Comment: Have you looked for the nvidia driver in the /lib/modules/<kernel> tree? I found sometimes the GUI install was only partial, and the actual driver didn't get built (do a command line apt-get --reinstall install in that case).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ubfan1 I managed to find out what the issue was. Reinstalling the driver from the terminal gave a

```
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc7-generic is not supported
```

In conclusion the problem is the Nvidia driver does not currently support my kernel until 4.2 is actually released.